# How can I center Stochastic over 0-line? (Pine Script V4)

Tags: pine-script

I am displaying a WaveTrend and Stochastic together in my indicator and I would really like to position the Stochastic over the WaveTrend rather than being scaled from 0-100. Is it possible to change the scale range or center position somehow?

[Stochastic Centered with Wave Trend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DwhU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your wavetrend is centered around zero, then just subtract 50 from the stoch value. If it needs rescaling, you can further multiply or divide that result to fit the desired range. For example :

```
scaled_stoch = (mystoch - 50) * 2
```

would give you stoch centered on zero with a -100 to 100 range